# Is it possible to avoid duplication of maven archiver configuration?

Tags: java, maven-2, maven

This is my parent `pom.xml`:

```
[...]
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.0</version>
  <configuration>
    <archive>
      <manifestEntries>
        <SCM-Revision>${buildNumber}</SCM-Revision>
      </manifestEntries>
    </archive>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.0</version>
  <configuration>
    <archive>
      <manifestEntries>
        <SCM-Revision>${buildNumber}</SCM-Revision>
      </manifestEntries>
    </archive>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
[...]
```

As you see, maven archiver is configured twice, with identically same parameters. Is it possible to avoid such duplication and configure it only once?

ps. I'm ready to migrate to Maven 3 to solve this problem.

Comment: no. only per pluging configuration is supported. maybe it will be added in a next version of maven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there's no good way. You can write your own Maven plugin and invoke WAR and JAR plugins with Mojo Executor: http://code.google.com/p/mojo-executor/
This is a more general problem with Maven 2: it doesn't allow any POM code reuse expect properties, and custom plugins. AFAIK things are going to improve with Maven 3.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Maven 3 Mixins is exactly for this purpose...

Comment: Apparently mixins will be part of Maven 3.1... they're not available in 3.0.